# Is it possible to set title length for ActionSheet in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using DisplayActionSheet method in my Xamarin.Forms application to prompt user with question. I want to add some additional information to question when I prompt user to help with their decision. The problem I'm facing is that my question gets truncated due to its length. It looks like 50 character is the limit for ActionSheet title. Is this the limit of ActionSheet or actually the limit of underlying AlertDialog on Android?

Example of truncated message:
[image: Example of truncated message.]

Is it possible to increase the limit of the title? OR is there any other component that I could use in order to display my question. My idea is that since my action required Yes/No answer from user, I could actually use popup body to display my message and then use Ok/Cancel buttons as Yes/No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there doesn't seem to be an easy solution for this issue, [this thread provides a workaround](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42210/android-page-displayactionsheet-need-more-text-room) for exactly your situation.